# mosh: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.7.dylib

Tags: protocol-buffers, homebrew

I really like `mosh` (http://mosh.mit.edu/) but after a `brew upgrade` it stopped working, yielding the below error.

```
> mosh example.com
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mosh-client
  Reason: image not found
Died at /usr/local/bin/mosh line 201.
```

Answer (score 7):

After some digging around I realised that this was due to `protobuf` had been upgraded and that `mosh` is hardcoded to use `protobuf 2.4.1`.

So all I had to do was revert from `protobuf 2.5.0` to `2.4.1`. On Mac with homebrew this is done by the following steps:

```
> brew versions protobuf
2.5.0    git checkout 019364d /usr/local/Library/Formula/protobuf.rb
2.4.1    git checkout 544209f /usr/local/Library/Formula/protobuf.rb
> git checkout 544209f /usr/local/Library/Formula/protobuf.rb
> brew unlink protobuf
> brew link protobuf
```

Comment: I couldn't build 2.4.1 on Yosemite but 2.5.0 seems to work as well.

Answer (score 5):

You shoud reinstall use:
https://mosh.mit.edu/#getting

DO NOT use `brew`, it work for me on MAC OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 1):

You could also update `brew` and then upgrade `mosh` to 1.2.4:

```
$ brew update
```

...

```
$ brew upgrade mobile-shell
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
mobile-shell 1.2.4
==> Upgrading mobile-shell
==> Downloading http://mosh.mit.edu/mosh-1.2.4.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mobile-shell/1.2.4
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/mobile-shell/1.2.4: 12 files, 1004K, built in 41 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, next line helped me:

```
brew reinstall protobuf
```